# Specify an index fill factor using Fluent API?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm using Entity Framework 7 (.NET Core 1) RC1. I'd like to create some indexes in a Migration. That part is easy enough, but I can't find any examples of how to specify the fill factor for the indexes.

The Context looks something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeObject>( entity =>
{
    entity.HasIndex( e => e.SomeProperty ).HasName(" IX_SomeObject_SomeProperty" );
}
```

And the Migration looks something like this:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_SomeObject_SomeProperty",
    schema: "dbo",
    table: "SomeObject",
    column: "SomeProperty" );
```

Is this just not supported by Fluent? Will I have to create the index manually in the Migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill factor is not supported as of EF Core RC1. You can use `migrationBuilder.Sql` to write manually the create index statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is what I suspected. I like Fluent well enough, but it's difficult to find decent documentation and there seems to be a lack of support for advanced operations.

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer according to the current situation (see the other answer)?

Answer (score 2):

It will be supported in EF Core 5.0 soon.

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Customer>()
    .HasIndex(e => e.Name)
    .HasFillFactor(90);
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#specify-sql-server-index-fill-factor